# Get parent Layout of widget and delete content

Tags: layout, widget, pyqt, parent

Currently having a problem with Pyqt as we need to delete the content of a layout that we cannot find.

This is basically what we have :

```
<Layout1>
  <Widget1>
    <Layout2>
      <Widget2>
        ...
```

We didn't have the Layout2 at first, and we didn't want to do

```
Widget1 = Widget2
```

So we add a Layout (Layout2), but as we are trying to change the content of Widget1, we have a class re-designed by ourself (that Looks like Qtdesigner generator), with a setupUi method with the Widget1 in parameter :

```
class ... :
  def setupUi(self, Widget1):
    #Creating Layout2 with Widget1 as parent
    #Creating Widget2 with Widget1 as parent
    #Adding Widget2 to Layout2
    ...
```

When adding the content of Widget1 to Widget1, we have no problem. Then we need to change the content and so we need to delete everything in Widget1 ( Well, we supposed that deleting was the solution ).

So here is the problem : When deleting the all stuff, we could not delete a mystical link between the 2 layouts. So we got messed up by the all thing and we're currently completely lost. We've been trying to use parent/children methods but we can't even get what we want...

So as I said :

How can I simply delete all Widget1 content and actually how to remove the Layout2?

Comment: That structure won't create any 'mystical link' between layouts. Can you show your code so that we get what you're _actually_ doing and what's not working?

Comment: Actually, we worked it out,

Answer (score 0):

We worked it out as I missed a line in the code of my collegue.

He was adding layout 2 to layout 1 and that was the problem.

So Layout just needs the children to be added to it.